# Insert into table With select and multiple value SQL server

Tags: jquery, sql-server

guys im trying to insert into a table with multiple value.

i want insert into purchasing table where customerID is gained from Customer table and
the SourceID is always 1 because it its default. i try query like this

```
insert into purchasing (customerID,SourceID) select customerID from Customer where    ************,'1'
```

but it returns erorr, can u guys help me, how to insert into table with multiple select and default insert

note:
*********** is any condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing wrong sql query syntax. Your sql query should be something like:

```
insert into purchasing (customerID,SourceID) select customerID, 1 from Customer where ***
```

Comment: if on case after select customerID i need to select SourceID from another table, can i put select customerid,(select ****** where **** ) where ***** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `select customerID, 1 from Customer`

Answer (score 1):

It is due to you have couple of errors in your sql. 
1. You have the closing ) but never opened it.
2. Include the default value in your query

```
insert into purchasing (customerID,SourceID) select customerID, 1 from Customer where ???
```